# Como crear filtro sin que se repita los Valores Seleccionados

Tags: php, jquery

**Index.php**:

```
<body>
    <div id="campo"></div>
    <div id="categoria">
        <?php include('selectPaisJquery.php');?>
    </div>
</body>
```

**selectPaisJquery.php**

```
<?php 
    include('configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function() {

  <?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idPais FROM pais";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
       $pais = utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idPais']);
  ?>
       var paisJq= "<?php echo $pais ?>";
       $('#categoria').append('<option value="'+ paisJq +'" >' + paisJq +'</option>');
  <?php  
    }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
  ?>

    $('option').click(function(){
      var valor = $(this).text();
         $('#campo').append(valor);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Especifica mejor tu duda, por favor.

Comment: Quiero que al dar click en una de las opciones escriba en el div llamado campo. Utilizando append; asi como esta en el codigo, Y la duda es que no se repita los valores de append dentro del div campo..

Comment: La etiqueta `<option>` es específicamente para ser usada dentro de un `<select>` como lo indica la [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp). Puedes cambiar a `<select>` o usar un `<input type="button" value="pais">`

Comment: Prefiero cambiarlo por un div ya que quiero que las categorias se me muestren en un div; sin necesidad de usar scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no quieres que se repitan los valores, puedes verificar si ya han sido agregados en el `div` utilizando el `indexOf` así:

```
$('option').click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).text();

    if($('#campo').text().indexOf(valor) == -1)
        $('#campo').append(valor);
});
```

Comment: Listo amigo funciona de maravilla gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Otra duda; Que propiedades o metodos se necesita para remover los textos que se asignaron en el div campo. Quiero que trabaje como un checkbox

Comment: @Gamez te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta con la nueva duda.